# Griffith's Experiment Conclusions

Tags: cell-biology, transformation

My teacher gave us these two questions on Griffith's experiment.

1. How did Griffith's experiment rule out that the rough cells could have used the capsules of the smooth cells to become pathogenic?
2. Why did Griffith know this experiment was important?

They said the answers were that

1. If they incorporated the broken capsule, then the next generation will not have the capsule, that's why we know it wasn't the capsules that made the rough cells pathogenic.
2. It ruled out proteins were the genetic material.

My problem with these answers is that it relies on knowledge we know. For the answer to number 1, the capsule could have contained genetic material and passed it on to the daughter cells (we know that isn't true but they didn't know proteins weren't the genetic material back then). I don't think the experiment ruled out the capsules were the factor making them pathogenic at all. I feel like all the experiment proved was that bacteria could transform. Beyond that, from my understanding, it didn't prove nor rule out what was leading it to transform - whether it was through protein or DNA.

What am I missing here? If my teacher is incorrect, what should I put down?